# How to get all Snapshot details using boto3?

Tags: boto3

How to get all the snapshots using boto3?
Below is the code to use way to get snapshot with volume id being know

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
volume_id = "something"
list_of_snapshots = []
vol = ec2.Volume(id=volume_id)
snapshots = vol.snapshots.all()
    try:
        for snapshot in snapshots:
            if snapshot:
                list_of_snapshots.append(snapshot.id)
        return list_of_snapshots[0]
    except:
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across using the below way of doing,

```
    from boto3 import client,ec2,Session

# print(help(Session))
s=Session(
# 'ec2-instance-connect',
    aws_access_key_id='youraccess_key_id',
    aws_secret_access_key='your secret access key',

    region_name='ap-south-1'
)
c=s.client('ec2')

Snapshots=c.describe_snapshots()

print(c.describe_snapshots()['Snapshots'])
```

#Above print is list of all snapshots being in dict with keys such as snapshotid, volumesize ... etc
with open('c:\Users\Murugaraju\Desktop\snapshots.txt','w') as f:
f.write(str(Snapshots))